# I need to find the number of business date in month

Tags: r, date

I have for example this date "2010-04-14". How can i find which business day, as number, is this date from the same month? My calendar is set up with NYSE holidays.

Answer (score 1):

If you check help file for `?strftime` you'll notice that if you convert your date to `Date` format, you'll be able to query it for day of the week.

```
xy <- "2010-04-14"
xy <- as.Date(xy)

strftime(xy, format = "%u")
[1] "3"
```

The documentation says

> %u Weekday as a decimal number (1–7, Monday is 1).

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough,  Let's say that in April 2010 there is 21 business days, i need to find which business day is 14th of April

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. Also specify what the expected result is (I'm guessing number of work weeks from 1st to (including?) 14th?